# Changing Xcode 5 settings for folders added to project

Tags: xcode, directory

When adding a folder to Xcode project there are two options - "Create groups for any added folders" and "Create folder references for any added folders."

My question is that if there is a way to change these settings once the folder is being added. I know we can remove the folder from the project and re-add them, but I wonder if there is some other way that is less idiotic to accomplish such task.

Comment: I thought the `…withXNamed:` methods searched your bundle for the given resource? Whether it's in a group or folder reference shouldn't matter as long as it's copied into your target bundle during build.

Comment: First of, it doesn't work on certain conditions. So having one condition doesn't prove anything. Secondly, this is completely off the topic.

Comment: It's off topic now that you've edited your question to exclude it. It wasn't when you originally posted.

Comment: I was only giving you an example, and you are trying to pick on the example, which is not what the question is about. I want people to focus on what matters so I removed the example. Perhaps it is a bad example - which I admit it is my fault.

Comment: Examples are important. Especially for questions like this for which the answer is a flat "No" and the question hints at, perhaps, a fundamental misunderstanding of the topic at hand. In addition to giving you an answer to the question asked (in the answer section below), I also wanted to let you know you're likely approaching the problem incorrectly. That's what the comments section is for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make much sense.

A group (yellow folder) in Xcode is just an abstract organizational concept. A group can contain one or more resources that actually get referenced/compiled/copied, but the group itself is just an placeholder that doesn't (necessarily) have any relation to the filesystem or target bundle.

A folder ref (blue folder), on the other hand, is the exact opposite. The folder itself is the only thing referenced/compiled/copied by Xcode and its contents are just blindly copied or whatever along with it. Xcode doesn't notice if you add, remove, or edit the contents. It only cares about the folder.

Because they are functionally opposite, converting from one to the other in-place would  end you with a pile of conflicts at best and lost data at worst. So Xcode doesn't provide that as an option.